# Is it possible to extract data from script with xPath?

Tags: javascript, xpath

I'm trying to extract the date (2018-11-20) from the script. Is it even possible to extract data from script?

```
<script>var dataLayer = [{"author":["David N. Haass"],"postdate_dl":"2018-11-20","region":["Canada"],"content type":"Article","pub type":"article","user category":"anonymous","nodeid_dl":"197954"}];</script>
```

I've this so far but it doesn't return any result:

```
//script[@dataLayer='postdate_dl']
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

XPath does not understand JavaScript, or JSON. The closest you can get with XPath selectors is the text node. You can cut the text node content with XPath string functions; depending on your tool, it may or may not include regexp matching, but even that is not powerful enough to parse JSON properly.

Depending on what exactly you are doing (and how confident you are regarding the content of the script), you might simply evaluate the script and access the variable, or cut up the string yourself to find the JSON and then `JSON.parse` it, or even go hardcore and build the AST of the script then evaluate it in a controlled way (e.g. using Esprima and Kudzu).